# How to tell time

Tags: american-english

From below options:
1) I work from 7 to 9
2) I work from 7 and 9

Which is a more proper way & why?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Both are theoretically valid, but without knowing what you are actually trying to say, and why you are confused between the two, we cannot help you. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] to see if your question can be improved. Our sister site, which FumbleFingers has already linked, may also be of interest.

Comment: Both may be theoretically valid/grammatical, but you’d have to have a pretty contrived setup to make 2 meaningful.

Comment: Maybe in 2) you mean "I work *between* 7 and 9"?

Answer (score 1):

In North American English (and at least some other dialects), one would say "I work from 7 to 9" if one meant their working hours were 7 a.m. to 9 a.m. (or 7-9 p.m.).  One could also say "I work between 7 and 9".

"I work at 7 and 9" implies you work both at 7:00 and 9:00 - perhaps at one time some days of the week, and at the other on other days.  It's quite ambiguous.  An English speaker is more likely to say "I work Monday to Wednesday at 7, and Thursday and Friday at 9", for example.